# NSString isEqualToString: does not work. Why?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I create an NSString using,

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:someBuffer length:sizeof(someBuffer) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I used NSLog to output myString and it displays "Hello".

If this is the case, then why does this fail.

```
NSString *helloString = @"Hello"

BOOL check = [myString isEqualToString:helloString];
```

Comment: If forgot to mention that "someBuffer" is defined as follows.

unsigned char someBuffer[64]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your myString variable is actually an NSString with a length of 64; the additional characters are probably undefined. What you most likely want to do is this:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:someBuffer length:strlen(someBuffer) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

This assumes a null-terminated C-string exists in your buffer.

Comment: Perfect. That works. You just need to add one casting operation as follows. Thank you.
 

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:someBuffer length:strlen((const char*)someBuffer) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Comment: Sorry should be (const char *)

Comment: Or, better yet, [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:someBuffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding].

Answer (score 4):

There are probably some trailing characters that you can't see when calling NSLog(). For example: whitespace, linefeeds or even '\0' characters.

Check [myString length] to see if it returns 5.